# pyspark use range between function in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

when i run

```
spark.sql(''' 
        select client,avg(amount) over (partition by client
         order by my_timestamp
         range between interval 30 days preceding and current row) as moving_avg_amount
         from my_table''')
```

it works.

but if i want to exclude the last X days - it fails.

```
... range between interval 30 days preceding and 12 days preceding ..
   or :
 ... range between interval 30 days preceding and interval 12 days preceding ..
```

what is the correct syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Spark SQL Window over interval of between two specified time boundaries - between 3 hours and 2 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242417/spark-sql-window-over-interval-of-between-two-specified-time-boundaries-betwee) it is suggested that range intervals do not work properly in SparkSQL.

Comment: thanks @RickyG , seems like an old bug then , don't see why it is not getting fixed....